# Share Image on Android Application from Unity Game

Tags: unity, android, screenshot

I've captured screenshot in my game when player dies. I've following code to capture screen shot.

```
RenderTexture rt = new RenderTexture (800, 600, 24);
        MainCamera.targetTexture = rt;
        Texture2D texture = new Texture2D (800, 600, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
        MainCamera.Render ();
        RenderTexture.active = rt;
        texture.ReadPixels (new Rect (0, 0, 800, 600), 0, 0);
        MainCamera.targetTexture = null;
        RenderTexture.active = null;
        Destroy (rt);
        byte[] bytes = texture.EncodeToPNG ();
        Directory.CreateDirectory (Application.persistentDataPath + "/GameOverScreenShot");
        File.WriteAllBytes (Application.persistentDataPath + "/GameOverScreenShot" + "/DiedScreenShot.png", bytes);
```

I am getting saved screenshot using following code.

```
byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes (Application.persistentDataPath +"/GameOverScreenShot" + "/BirdDiedScreenShot.png");

    Texture2D texture = new Texture2D (800, 600, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
    RectOffset tempOffset = new RectOffset (5, 5, 5, 5);
    texture.filterMode = FilterMode.Trilinear;
    texture.LoadImage (bytes);
    Sprite sprite = Sprite.Create (texture, new Rect (0, 0, 800, 400), new Vector2 (0.5f, 0.0f), 2.0f);
    ScreenShot_Image.GetComponent<Image> ().sprite = sprite;
```

Now, I want to share this screenshot on android application. As per my research i have got following code for that, but it is returning blank image.

```
//instantiate the class Intent
    AndroidJavaClass intentClass = new AndroidJavaClass("android.content.Intent");

    //instantiate the object Intent
    AndroidJavaObject intentObject = new AndroidJavaObject("android.content.Intent");

    //call setAction setting ACTION_SEND as parameter
    intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setAction", intentClass.GetStatic<string>("ACTION_SEND"));

    //instantiate the class Uri
    AndroidJavaClass uriClass = new AndroidJavaClass("android.net.Uri");

    //instantiate the object Uri with the parse of the url's file
    string destination = Application.persistentDataPath + "/GameOverScreenShot" + "/DiedScreenShot.png";
    AndroidJavaObject uriObject = uriClass.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("parse","file://"+destination);

    //call putExtra with the uri object of the file
    intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("putExtra", intentClass.GetStatic<string>("EXTRA_STREAM"), uriObject);

    //set the type of file
    intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setType", "image/*");

    //instantiate the class UnityPlayer
    AndroidJavaClass unity = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");

    //instantiate the object currentActivity
    AndroidJavaObject currentActivity = unity.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");

    //call the activity with our Intent
    currentActivity.Call("startActivity", intentObject);
```

What should I change in this??
Please help,
Advance Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Application.Persistant datapath stores your image inside of the apk, this is not what you want as your gallery will not see it.  Before you call WriteAllBytes, use this code:

```
string myFolderLocation = "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Screenshots/";

            if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(myFolderLocation))
            {
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(myFolderLocation);
            }
string myScreenshotLocation = myFolderLocation + "myFilename";

File.WriteAllBytes(myScreenshotLocation, bytes);
```

Then you refresh the android phone photo gallery, give it a minute before is actually is visible in the gallery, but you can see it inside that folder location as soon as you save the picture.

Note: mine works like a charm and its saving it on internal storage also.

Answer (score -1):

```
MainCamera.targetTexture = rt;
Texture2D texture = new Texture2D (800, 600, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);

//maybe you add this??

texture.apply();

MainCamera.Render ();
```

Comment: Please add some explanation as to how this will solve the problem.